# How do you scale up the address & back button in StreetView?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I am scaling up the controls sizes for my Google Maps, as my website serves an older audience and they greatly prefer larger UI.

> Setting the main Map control sizes, easy : `controlSize: 60, //<-pixels`
>
> Setting the StreetView sizes, easy : `controlSize: 60, //<-pixels`

But `Streetview.controlSize` does nothing to the address box and back button, they both remain small. I've scoured the Documentation and nothing exist in the [StreetViewAddressControlOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view#StreetViewPanoramaOptions).

I know I can go into the CSS and set `"gm-iv-container gm-iv-small-container"` styles for these elements; however, this violates Google's terms and conditions. Please let me know how one can increase the address and back button sizes in Javascript.

See my code below along with this image illustrating how frustratingly tiny the back button really is.

[Tiny Address & Back Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE9CZ.jpg)

StreetView Setup:

```
        const newStreetView = new window.google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
          map.getDiv(),
          {
            addressControlOptions: {position: window.google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER},
            controlSize: controlSize,
            enableCloseButton: true,
            fullscreenControl: false,
            visible: false,
          }
        );
        map.setStreetView(newStreetView);
```

Full Code:

```js
  static createMap(inputType, inputID, inputCenter, inputZoom, onComplete) {
    Maps.init(onValidate => {
      const mapType = inputType ? inputType : "default";
      const mapID = inputID ? inputID : _.uniqueId("prefix-");
      const formattedCenter = Maps.formatPosition(inputCenter);
      const center = formattedCenter ? formattedCenter : {lat: Maps.defaultLat, lng: Maps.defaultLng};
      const zoom = !isNaN(parseFloat(inputZoom)) ? inputZoom : Maps.defaultZoom;
      const controlSize = Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.05); // @MAGIC: controlSize set to 0.5vh

      /*====================
      Default Map
      ====================*/
      if(mapType === "default" || mapType === "editor") {
        
        // Create Map Parameters
        const mapParams = {
          center: center,
          controlSize: controlSize,
          disableDefaultUI: false,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {position: window.google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT, style: window.google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT},
          fullscreenControl: false,
          mapTypeControl: true,
          scaleControl: true,
          streetViewControl: true,
          zoom: zoom,
        };

        // Do not apply Streetview on the editor Map
        if(mapType === "editor") {
          mapParams.streetViewControl = false;
        }

        // Create the Map
        const map = new window.google.maps.Map(Maps.getMapDiv(mapID), mapParams);

        // Apply Streetview settings on the default Map
        if(mapType === "default") {
          new window.google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', () => {
            const newStreetView = new window.google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
              map.getDiv(),
              {
                addressControlOptions: {position: window.google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER},
                controlSize: controlSize,
                enableCloseButton: true,
                fullscreenControl: false,
                visible: false,
              }
            );
            map.setStreetView(newStreetView);
          });
        }
        
        // Create Map Pins
        const overlay = new window.google.maps.OverlayView();
        overlay.draw = function() {
          this.getPanes().markerLayer.id = 'markerLayer';
        } 
        overlay.setMap(map);
        onComplete(map);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported by the Maps JS API. I would strongly discourage using CSS to achieve that because indeed it might violate their TOS **and** it would be based on class names that aren't documented, which means your solution could stop working at any time if Google changes class names and/or the HTML structure.

What you *could* do instead is to disable that control and create your own [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) to replace it but that might come at a cost.

Also you can open a new feature request in their [issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853) and hope and wait (probably a long time) for Google to implement it. If you do so, kindly provide a link to this question in the feature request and a link to the feature request in your question.